# Como converter textbox em número e data no VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho um vba no Excel, entretanto o comando salva os lançamentos como texto, então não é possível aplicar qualquer fórmula. Já fiz algumas tentativas e pesquisa mas todas foram fracassadas, segue os códigos:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_gravar_Click()
Dim valor As Currency
Dim data As Date
valor = TextBox_valor
data = TextBox_data
Range("b11").Select
If Range("b12").Value <> "" Then
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Value = TextBox_data
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Value = ComboBox_categoria
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Value = TextBox_historico
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Value = ComboBox_movimento
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Value = TextBox_valor
Unload UserForm_lançamento
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o que esta faltando é alterar o formato da célula. Em Excel o formato padrão é texto.

1. Depois da linha: `Selection.Value = TextBox_data`; insira: `Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"`
2. Depois da linha: `Selection.Value = TextBox_valor`; insira: `Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"`

Para mais informações, de uma olhada aqui: https://www.excelhowto.com/macros/formatting-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Muito obrigado mas não funcionou a proposta, o que eu consegui resolver o problema adicionando uma conversão: 
Selection.Value = CCur(TextBox_valor)

Comment: Que bom que achou uma solucao! Obrigado por compartilhar.